# How to add additional rows to Tapestry Grid?

Tags: java, datagrid, row, tapestry, tabular

I have a Grid together with its GridDataSource. However, I want to show one column of that grid under all the others.

Here's the example:

I have this so far:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 |
========================================================
| Data 11  | Data 12  | Data 13  | Data 14  | Data 15  |
--------------------------------------------------------
| Data 21  | Data 22  | Data 23  | Data 24  | Data 25  |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to achieve this:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
=============================================
| Data 11  | Data 12  | Data 13  | Data 14  |
|                  Data 15                  |
---------------------------------------------
| Data 21  | Data 22  | Data 23  | Data 24  |
|                  Data 25                  |
---------------------------------------------
```

I was thinking of try to add a `<tr>` after first 4 column cells and put my DataX5 inside it, but that's got me nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use my [griddecorator](http://tapestry-stitch.uklance.cloudbees.net/griddecoratordemo) mixin and apply a [GridRowDecorator](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/stitch/model/GridRowDecorator.java) to each row. The decorator creates a new row after the current and moves the last element to the new row.

If not, create your own mixin which tweaks the DOM once the grid has rendered. You might want to take a look at my [gridcollapse](http://tapestry-stitch.uklance.cloudbees.net/gridcollapsedemo) mixin where I move columns and rows about and add rowspans.

Comment: You sir, are an inspiration :)

Answer (score 0):

Another, slightly dodgy, way is to use outputRaw and a custom cell to get around tapestry's properly formed XML requirements.

Eg

```
<t:grid source="..." value="current">
   <p:column5Cell>     
      <t:outputRaw value="&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td colspan='4'&gt;" />
      ${current.column5}
   </p:column5Cell>
</t:grid>
```

Comment: Just a quick question. If I do this approach, ajax updating doesn't work.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridColumns.setupRender(GridColumns.java:112)

Comment: Are you referring to ```inplace="true"``` or your own custom ajax event? It's hard to know without seeing code (or knowing what version of tapestry you are using). It seems like the nested GridColumns component is trying to render but either the Grid or the data model is null. How are you storing your model? Flash persistence? Perhaps you need to re-populate the model in your ajax event?

Comment: Once more, I feel like an idiot. I accidentally deleted one line of code that manages my model. :)